# How to compare indices of a list to a float?

Tags: python

Nested list to be iterated over

```
cost =[[125900], [115000],
[105900],
[85000],
[150000],
[155249],
[97500]]
```

Initialize variables

```
index = 0
cost_len = len(cost)
below_avg = 0
above_avg = 0
total = 0
```

For loop to calculate the total of all elements in cost

```
 for i in cost:
    total = total + sum(i)
    print(total)
```

Calculating the average of cost

```
avg = total / len(cost)
```

Attempt to calculate whether indices are above or below avg

```
for i in cost:
    while index <= cost_len:
        if i > avg:
            above_avg+=1
        elif i < avg:
            below_avg +=1
        index+=1
```

When attempting to evaluate the indices of cost, it returns "TypeError: unorderable types: list() > float()". How would I compare the indices of the list with the variable avg?

Comment: In last code bit, what is `index`, `cost_len`, `above_avg`, `below_avg`? They are never shown to be initialized.

Comment: No worries. I retracted my close vote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to flatten the list if you want to compare multiple elements in each sublist:

```
total = sum(sum(x) for x in cost)
cost_len = sum(len(x) for x in cost)
avg = total / cost_len
above = sum([sum([y > avg for y in x for x in cost])])
below = sum([sum([y < avg for y in x for x in cost])])
exact = cost_len - (above + below)
```

A couple of points about this solution:

1. The computation for `total` and `cost_len` use generators instead of creating lists from the results. This saves you some memory and possibly execution time since intermediate results do not require additional storage.
2. `above` and `below` are nested generators, basically equivalent to the nested loop you were trying to do.

Here is an explanation of what your final nested loop does and how to fix it:

```
for i in cost:
    while index <= cost_len:
        if i > avg:
            above_avg+=1
        elif i < avg:
            below_avg +=1
        index+=1
```

`i` loops over the elements of `cost`, but the inner `while` loop prevents it from doing anything after the first value of `i` is processed. Notice that the value of `i` does not change in the inner loop, so the comparisons are done over and over for the first `i`, and not at all for the others since `index` will be `cost_len + 1` by then. To preserve the double loop structure you have, you can do as follows:

```
for i in cost:
    for j in i:
        if j > avg:
            above_avg+=1
        elif j < avg:
            below_avg +=1
```

At that point, you do not really need `index`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming one element per sub-list, flatten seems to be the best:

```
flat_cost = [x[0] for x in cost]
total = sum(flat_cost)
avg = total /len(cost)
above = len([x for x in flat_cost if x > avg])
below = len([x for x in flat_cost if x < avg])
```

Comment: For an arbitrary number of elements per list, you could flatten them with [i for j in cost for i in j]

Comment: Thank you, very clean and precisely what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to be dealing with lists of numbers or arrays of numbers then I would suggest you use Numpy (http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/index.html) for this task:

```
import numpy as np

cost = np.array([[125900],
 [115000],
 [105900],
 [85000],
 [150000],
 [155249],
 [97500]])

cost-np.average(cost)

>>>array([[  6678.71428571],
       [ -4221.28571429],
       [-13321.28571429],
       [-34221.28571429],
       [ 30778.71428571],
       [ 36027.71428571],
       [-21721.28571429]])
```

The `cost - np.average(cost)` is a way to use Numpy's broadcasting feature.  You can subtract a single value (`np.average(cost)`) from an array (`cost`) and it will do the subtraction for the whole array which gives you the answer array.

Comment: This isn't specifically what I was looking for but I will try solving it with Numpy to familiarize myself with the module, thank you.